# PostgreSQL conditional use of function parameters

Tags: function, postgresql, select, parameters, conditional-statements

I'd like to know how to use a function parameter conditionaly. This is my function, and you can read the comment inside the query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mediabase.select_media(sysEnvironment character varying, statusId integer)
RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  ref refcursor; 
BEGIN
  OPEN ref FOR 

  SELECT media.id, media.title, media.unique_filename, media.owner_id, media.status_id, media.location_name_id, media.upload_user_id, media.upload_ip, media.metadata_id, media.type_id, media.description, media.system_environment, media.upload_date, media.gps_location, media.language_id, media_publications.publication_id, media.limitations, media_categories.category_id, metadata.width, metadata.height, metadata.equipment, metadata.copyright, metadata.creation_time, metadata.file_format, metadata.resolution, metadata.resolution_unit, metadata.gps_longitude, metadata.gps_latitude, metadata.artist, metadata.color_space, metadata.gps_altitude, metadata.software_used, metadata.user_comment
  FROM mediabase.media, mediabase.metadata, mediabase.media_categories, mediabase.media_publications
  WHERE media.metadata_id = metadata.id
  AND media.id = media_categories.media_id
  AND media.id = media_publications.media_id
  -- Problem: this CASE doesn't work of course
  CASE statusId <> -1 THEN
    AND media.status_Id = statusId
  END
  -- End problem
  AND media.system_environment = sysEnvironment
  ORDER BY media.upload_date DESC;

  RETURN ref;                       
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

I only need to use the 'statusId' parameter, if it's different from -1, otherwise I'll recieve no results as there of-course is no status -1. Later on, I'll need to add some more filters of that sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
AND (media.status_Id = statusId OR statusId = -1)
```

It wont check `media.status_Id = statusId` if `statusId = -1`.

Comment: Although the solution is correct and simpler than a `case` there is nothing to prevent it from checking the left side.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Haven't tested on a full procedure, but [`this`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5880c/3) example shows, that query optimizer can omit useless checks.